# Getting started with Node.js security: Injection

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, express, code-injection

**Premise**: Web application built with MEAN stack, developer (myself) writing his first web app. Current stage: avoiding security issues.

**My attempt**: Accordingly, I am trying to prevent code injection. After reading a few posts, I am now validating any user input in POST requests, in order to avoid special characters such as `< $ %` and other ones.

**Questions**: Is it actually this the correct way of avoiding code injection? Am I reinventing the wheel by writing my own regex (and code) to spot bad input?

Comment: No. Do not prevent special characters. It will just break your app / make it unusable. To avoid security issues, use proper *escaping* in the appropriate places.

Comment: As long as you don't use `eval()` on user request data, you are safe from code injection. User input is treated as String, not as executable code.

Comment: What kind of injection are you talking about? Are you thinking of some kind of Mongo attack, or cross-site scripting, or something else? It might be useful to explain in more detail what you're trying to prevent.

Comment: @alesc: Depends. It can happen that you execute user input without using `eval`, e.g. when echoing html that contains script elements or so. Or user inputted strings are passed to some function that interprets them as a DSL.

Comment: @Bergi echoing malicious HTML/JS code is executed on the client side, not the server side. It is of course still a threat, but you cannot execute user input on the server side without `eval()`. To protect the client side, you have to escape HTML special chars. You can look at the PHP's [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function for reference. Also, if you are using a database, don't forget to escape that too. SQL injections are sadly still one of the most common security issues.

Comment: @alesc: Yes, that's what I meant with "interpret a DSL".

Comment: Thanks all! @Bergi, if I understand correctly I should not send a response to the user saying: "You cannot use this character", rather replace/delete the character and save what the user sent?

Comment: @GioPan: No, you shouldn't even delete it - you should replace it with a representation of the character that works in the target environment (saving). That's what [escaping does](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence). Notice that you shouldn't write the escape function yourself, every proper environment will provide you one when escaping is necessary

Comment: @TrevorDixon Mongo attacks for now, but with the general purpouse of eventually preventing also cross-site scripting (as well as other attacks I will get to learn from now on).

Comment: @GioPan: you just have to follow one simple rule: sanitize all user input. And the process of doing that depends on what you want to do with the input: either display it on a web page, store it into a database or make database queries on the input. If you want some concrete answers, you will have to specify what do you want to do with your user input.